# The sandpiles on the beach

Tags: mathematics, graph-theory

We call a convex polyhedron a sandpile if one of the faces, called base, has a common edge with all the other faces. Furthermore, each vertex is linked with three edges. We consider the sandpiles by vertex translations, rotations and symmetries close. Therefore, there are 3 sandpiles with a hexagonal base:

[image]

How many sandpiles have a base with 9 edges?

Comment: By some graph theory, I know there are going to be 7 internal vertices in each of your sandpiles with a 9-gon base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

27

> This is dual to triangulations of a 9-gon that, without symmetries, are counted by a Catalan number.  Taking symmetry into account leaves the sequence [A000207](http://oeis.org/A000207) first considered by Motzkin: starting from a triangle base, it's 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 12, 27, 82...

> For the duality, consider the hexagon examples. Build a triangulated hexagon from each one in the following way: The vertices of the new hexagon are are midpoints of the base hexagon edges.  Connect these new vertices if their corresponding faces share an edge.  The top left figure becomes a hexagon containing an N, the top right has three internal edges emanating from the left vertex, and the bottom figure has a triangle inside.  In this MathWorld [entry](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalanNumber.html), in the two rows of 7 triangulated hexagons, these are row 2 #6, row 1 #7, and row 2 #4, respectively.  As you can see from that list, the other 11 triangulations are equivalent to one of these three.